# Revoke user select not working in postgre

Tags: postgresql

I have created a user as

```
create user dummy_role;
REVOKE SELECT ON "dispute_data" FROM dummy_role;
```

But when I am trying to query with select, it is working perfectly fine

```
set role dummy_role;
select * from dispute_data;
```

what am I  missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot explicitly deny a user a privilege.

The user is newly created, so it does not yet have any privileges on the table. The attempt to revoke the privileges that were never granted is a no-operation. Since your user is not yet a member of any role, the privilege must have been granted to `PUBLIC`. To revoke that, try

```
REVOKE SELECT ON dispute_data FROM PUBLIC;
```

That will deny the privilege from all other users as well, unless they were explicitly granted that privilege.